# str_getcsv on a tab-separated file

Tags: php, csv

This works for `comma` separated file:

```
array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));
```

but this doesn't work for `tab` separated file:

```
array_map('str_getcsv("\t")', file('file.TLD'));
```

Comment: try to setup an anonymous function instead

Comment: You can't pass additional arguments to functions used in a callback in this way: use a closure instead

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
array_map(function($v){return str_getcsv($v, "\t");}, file('file.csv'));
```

Example `*.csv` file:

```
a   b   c   d 
1   2   3   4
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) )
```