# Exclude text to valid array

Tags: php

i have a text and i want convert it to array by exclude but i cant get true array

```
# SRC-ADDRESS DST-ADDRESS PACKETS BYTES SRC-USER DST-USER 0 10.40.47.48 216.58.205.211 12 822 2 1 10.40.47.48 102.132.97.21 66 9390 2 2 184.106.10.77 10.40.47.252 10 1819 1 3 10.40.47.252 104.27.155.225 1 41 1 4 10.40.47.252 144.76.103.6 5 878 1 5 102.132.97.35 10.40.47.252 11 1159 1 6 10.40.47.252 52.169.53.217 1 397 1 7 104.27.155.225 10.40.47.252 1 52 1
```

and i want result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [.id] => *0
            [src-address] => 10.40.47.50
            [dst-address] => 185.144.157.141
            [packets] => 6
            [bytes] => 1349
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [.id] => *1
            [src-address] => 195.122.177.151
            [dst-address] => 10.40.47.48
            [packets] => 4
            [bytes] => 174
            [dst-user] => 2
        )
....
```

i try this but it is wrong 
    $arr = exclude(" ",$text);

edit :

i can get text by another way

```
 0 src-address=108.177.15.188 dst-address=10.40.47.252 packets=1 bytes=52 dst-user="1" 1 src-address=10.40.47.48 dst-address=172.217.19.150 packets=11 bytes=789 src-user="2" 2 src-address=184.106.10.77 dst-address=10.40.47.252 packets=26 bytes=5450 dst-user="1"
```

Comment: could be you are looking for explode $arr = explode(" ",$text);

Comment: is it tab delimited? If so parse it as a csv

Comment: Is the input really all one long line?

Comment: I have modified the array

Comment: yes  ! @PatrickQ

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how possible this is going to be.  Not in a flexible way, anyway.  First, you have `[.id] => *0`, but that doesn't seem to match anything.  Second, your inner arrays in your example output have different lengths.  Third, you'll have to have a fixed definition of what your "headers" are and where the "data" starts.  I'd highly suggest seeing if you can get the source data constructed differently.

Comment: ok @PatrickQ what about this 0 src-address=108.177.15.188 dst-address=10.40.47.252 packets=1 bytes=52 dst-user="1" 1 src-address=10.40.47.48 dst-address=172.217.19.150 packets=11 bytes=789 src-user="2" 2 src-address=184.106.10.77 dst-address=10.40.47.252 packets=26 bytes=5450 dst-user="1"

Comment: @PHPProgrammer What about it?  As input or as output?  Why are some values quoted and others not?  If input, is it still all one line?  Please update/edit your question with relevant information.  As you can probably see, long strings of data do not format well in comments .

Comment: @PatrickQ this is output from mikrotik  , ok now i have new edit

Comment: @PHPProgrammer Thank you.  That format might be better, but it is still going to be tough without a line delimiter.

Comment: @PHPProgrammer Quick logic to try: explode by space, loop through each, explode by `=`, if there's only one part, create a new primary row in the result array, if two parts, add a key-value-pair in the current row.  If I have time, I'll write up an answer.  No promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, one way would be to first [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your input by " " (space).  You loop through each element/row of the resulting array.  Then you explode each of *those* by `=` (equals sign).  If the result of *that* explode is a single-element array, you know you should start a new row and create a key-value pair using your special `.id` key.  If the count of the result is two, take the first part and make it the key of a new key-value pair in the current row, and take the second part and make it the value of that key-value pair.

There's a bit of a wrinkle in the fact that some of your source values are quoted, but you seem to want them not quoted in the result.  To handle that we do a lose equality check on the value to see if it is the same when converted to an integer or not.  If it is, then we convert it to remove the quotes.

```
$inputText = '0 src-address=108.177.15.188 dst-address=10.40.47.252 packets=1 bytes=52 dst-user="1" 1 src-address=10.40.47.48 dst-address=172.217.19.150 packets=11 bytes=789 src-user="2" 2 src-address=184.106.10.77 dst-address=10.40.47.252 packets=26 bytes=5450 dst-user="1"';

$result = array();

$spaceParts = explode(" ", $inputText);

foreach($spaceParts as $part)
{
    $subParts = explode("=", $part);

    if(count($subParts) == 1)
    {
        $resultIndex = (isset($resultIndex) ? $resultIndex+1 : 0);
        $result[$resultIndex] = array(".id" => "*".$part);
    }
    else if(count($subParts) == 2)
    {
        $result[$resultIndex][$subParts[0]] = ((int)$subParts[1] == $subParts[1] ? (int)$subParts[1] : $subParts[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        // unexpected, handle however you want
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66d6f4c13ca845a6f9d03c22e1807529a077a1ff)

Comment: @PHPProgrammer May I suggest that you don't refer to everyone as "bro". Some might take offense to that.

Comment: why ?? i cant understand !? i mean brother ?!

Comment: @PHPProgrammer Would you refer to your mother, sister, or daughter as "bro"? What about a respected elder? Do not presume to know to whom you are talking. Additionally, in American culture, "bro" is often (not always) said with a certain level of aggression.  There is simply no need for the reference.  Just say "thanks".

Comment: and when we say brother we have the sense of closeness and respect for the other

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the string in using `str_getcsv` replacing the delimiter with whatever the string is delimited by.

`var_dump(str_getcsv($input, ","));`

Note the manual states that the delimiter must be one char long. If wanting a tab or multiple spaces you will need to look into the answer:
[str_getcsv on a tab-separated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690855/str-getcsv-on-a-tab-separated-file)

[str-getcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) php manual

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want this result bro Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [.id] => *0, [src-address] => 10.40.47.50, [dst-address] => 185.144.157.141,[packets] => 6, [bytes] =>1349
        )
    [1] => Array
        ([.id] => *1, [src-address] => 195.122.177.151, [dst-address] => 10.40.47.48, [packets] => 4, [bytes] => 174,[dst-user] => 2
        )

Comment: I see! Is there anything that will signify a line break? How are you getting the input?

Comment: no ): but what about this 0 src-address=108.177.15.188 dst-address=10.40.47.252 packets=1 bytes=52 dst-user="1" 1 src-address=10.40.47.48 dst-address=172.217.19.150 packets=11 bytes=789 src-user="2" 2 src-address=184.106.10.77 dst-address=10.40.47.252 packets=26 bytes=5450 dst-user="1"

Comment: you could write a regex for that

Comment: `src-address=[\d.]* dst-address=[\d.]* packets=\d* bytes=\d* dst-user="\d*" \d` then use preg match to capture each 'line'

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that could work but I would recoment using the csv methods instead to read the data in . And it is unclear how your data should be actually mapped to header.

```
$header = "# SRC-ADDRESS DST-ADDRESS PACKETS BYTES SRC-USER DST-USER ";
$input = "# SRC-ADDRESS DST-ADDRESS PACKETS BYTES SRC-USER DST-USER 0 10.40.47.48 216.58.205.211 12 822 2 1 10.40.47.48 102.132.97.21 66 9390 2 2 184.106.10.77 10.40.47.252 10 1819 1 3 10.40.47.252 104.27.155.225 1 41 1 4 10.40.47.252 144.76.103.6 5 878 1 5 102.132.97.35 10.40.47.252 11 1159 1 6 10.40.47.252 52.169.53.217 1 397 1 7 104.27.155.225 10.40.47.252 1 52 1 ";
$string = str_replace($header, "", $input );
$delimiter  = " ";
$columns = 6;


$splitData = explode($delimiter, $string);

$result = [];
$i= 0;
foreach ($splitData as $key => $value) {
     $result[$i][] = $value;
    if (($key+1) % $columns == 0 ){
        $i++;
    }

}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: This doesn't create the inner arrays as associative array as desired by the OP

Comment: Sorry - yes forgot to assign header column to make key pairs as request in question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the second example with the `0 src-address=108.177.15.188 dst-address=10.40.47.252 packets=1 bytes=52 dst-user="1"` format, there are 6 entries:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) {
                       parse_str("id=".implode("&", $v), $output);
                       return $output;
                    }, array_chunk(explode(' ', $text), 6));
```

- Explode the array on spaces
- Chunk the array into 6 entries per element
- Map to a function that implodes each array on `&` and parse it as a query string